# How to write thread-safe methods?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety

Is this good practice and enough to ensure thread-safety to the method `DoSomething` in VB.NET?

```
Public Class MyForm : Inherits Form

    Public Sub DoSomething(parameter As Object)
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(Sub() DoSomething(parameter))
        Else
            'Do Something
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you may mean something different by *thread-safety* than the usual definition of the term.  The normal meaning of the term is that the same method or object may be called by multiple threads simultaneously without errors or negative side effects.  Typically, that kind of thread-safety is accomplished via statelessness and locking (e.g. `SyncLock`).

However, in your example, the code is not attempting to provide that kind of thread-safety, or at least not directly.  It does accomplish that kind of thread-safety, but only by forcing all invocations to be executed on the same single thread (the UI thread).  WinForm applications (which I presume this is) require that all UI work is done on the UI thread.  Therefore, if a method which does something with the UI is called from another thread, it must first invoke back to the UI thread before completing its work.  For that specific scenario, the code you have posted is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer! I've used `SyncLock` sometimes and I understand what you mean, but I don't understand, due to my lack of knowledge, what *statelessness* is. Could you just give a hint for me to go and learn about it?

Comment: What I mean by that is, if the method or object maintains no internal state, then it is generally considered to be thread safe.  In other words, as long as the methods ask for all data as input parameters and return all results as a return value, and don't read or write data to any of it's own fields, then it's safe to be called by many threads simultaneously.  If the object maintain values between invocations, and especially if invoking its methods or properties cause its state to change, then it's not safe, since its state will be unstable.

Comment: I guess maybe the better term for me to have used was _Immutability_, since that's more general.

Comment: don't worry, I understood it perfectly from your explanation.